# Why do I get errors when building android programs in buildozer? kivymd2.0

Tags: kivymd

ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.film.canary/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/materialyoucolor/quantize/celebi.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)

buildozer
requirements = python3,
charset-normalizer,
kivy,
pillow,
https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,
materialyoucolor,
exceptiongroup,
asyncgui,
asynckivy

I add charset-normalizer to requirements ，but it not work